# Clear Cache on exit Chrome

Tags: chrome

I'm looking for a plugin/extension/app/whateverchromecallsthemnow for Chrome that will clear the Cache and *only the cache* when I exit Chrome.

So to break it down:

- Clears cache on exit.
- Leaves history as is.
- Leaves downloads as is.
- Leaves cookies as is.
- No interaction needed on exit.

A relatively simple plugin is prefered, basically the polar opposite of something like [Click & Clean](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/clickclean/ghgabhipcejejjmhhchfonmamedcbeod?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

I work a lot with images on websites, so my cache can grow quite large very quickly. My HDD isn't that big, so I'm getting tired of having to clear the cache weekly, hence this request.

Comment: Can you code? Even just a little? If you don't find an answer here, then just sue a script that launches Chrome, waits, then deletes the cache directory?

Comment: An extension will typically be written in JavaScript, and as far as I know (or can Google) there's no way to clear the cache with just JavaScript. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13291751/5463636) for more detail.